# Looking for a story about a Sun that becomes self-aware

Tags: story-identification, novel, sentience, solar-system

Trying to find this book. In it, over eons of time, a sun actually begins to think. He becomes self-aware, and then, one day MOVES itself, and its system.

I read this approximately 10-15 years ago, in paperback format, I believe.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are quite a few stories about sentient stars, so any more information about the story will be helpful.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: I also want to know the answer. A related book is: If the stars are gods. Gregory Benford and Gordon Ecklund https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/455947.If_the_Stars_Are_Gods

Comment: And then there's Olaf Stapledon's classic [_Star Maker_](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1142) (1937), in which stars are moved by sentient beings living on planets, and become so upset that they go nova, incinerating the planets. Eventually the planetary beings realize that the stars are sentient.

Answer (score 6):

The book that comes to mind is the 1990 novel [The World at the End of Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_at_the_End_of_Time) written by Frederik Pohl.

The story follows colonists from Earth who have settled a planet orbiting a star inhabited by a powerful sentient being (Wan-To) which is engaged in a war with neighboring sentient stars. Wan-To itself is one of the characters in the novel as I recall. Wan-To accelerates the star away and carries its planetary system (and the colonists) with it. By the time their sun slows down the colonists find themselves hundreds of billions of years in the future due to relativistic effects.

Comment: THANK YOU RobertF. That's it! I really appreciate you remembering. lol, It's been bothering me for a long time.

Answer (score 5):

I've read the book you're talking about and now I'm curious too.

This one is more likely the answer, though I don't recall reading this author before.

**"FROM A CHANGELING STAR"** by Jeffrey A Carver

> Across the galaxy, tensions are rising between the authoritarian
>   Tandesko Triune and the free-marketeers of the Auricle Alliance.
>   Nevertheless, scientists of both sides have come together in Project
>   Starmuse, to observe the giant star Betelgeuse as it goes supernova.
>   At the space station imbedded inside the roiling star, the team
>   anxiously awaits the return of the one man essential to the success of
>   the project. On Kantano's World, astronomer Willard Ruskin must
>   discover why someone has infected him with nano-agents - artificially
>   intelligent, microscopic computers, which alter his appearance, his
>   memory, his very DNA. Drawn into a conflict from which not even death
>   will free him, Ruskin must find a way to reach Betelgeuse before his
>   enemies sabotage Starmuse...and humankind's future among the stars. A
>   harrowing journey from inside the human cell - to the mind of a dying
>   star.

[http://www.amazon.com/From-Changeling-Star-Jeffrey-Carver/dp/0759295956](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0759295956)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer...

In "Sun Diver" by David Brin, humans discover sentient life living as plasma at the surface of the Sun.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundiver

I vaguely recall another novel more along the lines of what you described but I can't add any details to your description.

Answer (score -1):

Very similar to part of the story in the novel 'The Silkie' by A.E VanVogt

Comment: Think about adding some link to your title or author ;)

Comment: {nods} Because I'm not seeing anything about the sun becoming sentient reading through http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silkie_%28novel%29